# Setter Injection with @ComponentImport

Tags: spring, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Hi I'm trying to modify a Confluence Plugin to check every Network request against the `OutboundWhitelist`, however the plugin is written in a way where adding it into the constructor breaks quite a few things and causes quite a headache.
I wanted to know if it is possible to somehow do this in a different way.

I tried using `@ComponentImport` on the field itself and tried other things like `@Inject` and `@Autowired`.
However with all of these the `OutboundWhitelist` was null and the resulting code did not work.

Did I miss something or is adding `@ComponentImport` to the Constructor really the only way to achieve this behaviour?

Any help is appreciated.
Edit: Added Code Samples.

This is what I'd like to avoid

```
private final OutboundWhitelist outboundWhitelist;


public YourMacro(@ComponentImport OutboundWhitelist outboundWhitelist) {
   this.outboundWhitelist = outboundWhitelist;
}
```

This is what I'd like to do:

```
public void setOutboundWhitelist(OutboundWhitelist ow) {  
    this.outboundWhitelist = ow;  
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added example code.

Answer (score 0):

If **OutboundWhitelist** is a bean, you can use ComponentAccessor to get it directly in the code depending on the environment:

```
OutboundWhitelist list=ComponentAccessor.getComponent(OutboundWhitelist.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `OutboundWhitelist` instance is defined a bean first:
In any class annotated as `@Configuration` add this

```
@Bean
public OutboundWhitelist outboundWhitelist() {
  return new OutboundWhitelist() //Or any other code that creates and returns the instance of OutboundWhitelist
}
```

Than in any class (such as your class `YourMacro`) where you need that bean
just simply do this:

```
@Resource
private OutboundWhitelist outboundWhitelist;
```

Of course, your `YourMacro` class should be marked as `@Component` or any annotation that includes `@Component`, such as `@Service` `@Controller` etc